# I am facing some problems with json parsing

Tags: android, json, android-json

```
{"success":"true",
"groups":[  
   {  
      "groupId":"c20f2353-1f13-4ea0-8283-ghhjc4dcc725251b",
      "name":"hb",
      "description":"hjj",
      "image":null,
      "membersCount":1,
      "groupType":"chaddt",
      "productCategeory":"bdfjgh",
      "members":[  
         {  
            "memberId":"0031ea31-a71c-49f8ddbff6-8adaa310db02",
            "memberName":"ddddsnta",
            "contactId":"5a303564dd-2349-4cca-a190-f36f28ff54cb",
            "contactName":"dssnta",
            "role":"member"
         }
      ],

   }
]
}
```

This is my json.I am having some difficulty in parsing this.I am trying this solution.please suggest some ideas how to parse this type of json.Thanks for your answer

```
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("groups");

for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
     groupid = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("groupId");
    String name = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("name");
    String description =jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("description");
    String membersCount = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("membersCount");
    String intrested = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("productCategeory");
    JSONArray memberJsonArray = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("members");
    for (int j = 0; j < memberJsonArray.length(); j++) {
        String memberNamename = memberJsonArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("contactName");
        String contactId = memberJsonArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("contactId");
        String role = memberJsonArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("role");
        GroupsDto groupDtoData = new GroupsDto();
        groupDtoData.setGroupName(name);
        groupDtoData.setGroupServerId(groupid);
        System.out.println("groupid"+groupid);
        groupDtoData.setGroupDescription(description);
        groupDtoData.setProductCategory(intrested);
        System.out.println("descr"+intrested);
        groupDtoData.setGetmemberCount(membersCount);
        groupDtoData.setGroupmembername(memberNamename);
        System.out.println("membernames"+memberNamename);
        groupDto.add(groupDtoData);
        db.addGroups(groupDtoData);
}
```

This is my json.I am having some difficulty in parsing this.I am trying this solution.please suggest some ideas how to parse this type of json.Thanks for your answer

Comment: Json not valid missing comma after  "productCategeory": "bdfjgh"

Comment: What is your issue? Any errors?

Comment: For each member it will add a new list item                                     I/System.out: groupid3369b480-102d-4557-a934-bb07a21efc62
I/System.out: descr x
I/System.out: membername ram
I/System.out: groupid3369b480-102d-4557-a934-bb07a21efc62
I/System.out: descrfhjdf
I/System.out: membernames syam

Comment: @prsandroid So how do you want it to be?

Comment: I want the member should come in a single line like   groupid,desc,intrest,member@K Neeraj Lal

Comment: @prsandroid Show a screenshot of what you get now and what you are expecting.

Comment: If the members array have 3 member,The list view will show 3 groups.But I expect in a single group name there are 3 member but it comes as a 3 different groups with same groupname and id@K Neeraj Lal

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON response does not have any array name.

Instead of this :

```
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("groups");
```

Use This:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray(yourResponseStringHere);
```

Answer (score 0):

It just needed to use Gson library and create corresponding class with your json file. 
Gson : https://github.com/google/gson

Answer (score 0):

Check this answer .It may help you fixing this.

```
    JsonArray jarray=response.getJsonArray("groups");

      for(int i=0;i<jarray.length();i++)
      {
       JsonObject jobj=jarray.getJsonObject(i);
         String groupId=jobj.optString("groupId");
        //do like this for all
          //to get members
          JsonArray jarray2=jobj.getJsonArray("members");
           for(int j=0;j<jarray2.length();j++)
           {
           JsonObject jobj2=jarray2.getJsonObject(j);
             String memberId=jobj2.optString("memberId");

             //do this for all 
           }
       }
```